# "Missing \endcsname inserted" from babel

Tags: xetex, babel

I'm typesetting a document in English in which I quote texts in Latin and occasionally give a word in Hebrew. I suspect a recent Babel update (3.25) has broken something, because I now get a "Missing `\endcsname` inserted" error. I've reduced the code that causes the error to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=american, latin]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Georgia}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{latin}{Vita} means life.
\end{document}
```

Typesetting this with XeLaTeX produces the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \bbl@sbcp@latin 
l.8 \foreignlanguage{latin}{Vita}
                                  means life.
```

If I remove the `\babelfont` line, I instead get a similar error for `\bbl@sbcp@american` on line 9 (`\end{document}`).

If I don't import the Hebrew INI, it works, but then I can't wrap Hebrew words in `foreignlanguage{hebrew}`, which results in misplaced vowel points (using the Cardo font).

It also works with TeXLive 2017.

Comment: Without the line `\babelfont{rm}{Georgia}` it works here in TeXlive 2018, and the output looks like normal text (I mean, no italic, etc... - I have no idea how the output should be).

Comment: I think it should work if Georgia font is right installed since it now works with `\babelfont{rm}{Ubuntu}` in my system.

Comment: Make a bug report here: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e, looks like a problem in babel 3.25, in 3.24 it works.

Comment: With lualatex it works too (at least I get no error).

Comment: I added a bug report: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/84

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer for filing the bug report. It looked like a bug, but I wasn't sure. I've restored the backup of babel 3.24 with the TeX Live Utility.